# How to return a SODA_DOCUMENT_T in ORDS as JSON/RESULTSET?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-ords

If I want to use PL/SQL to query my JSON documents in a Oracle database (configured for JSON database, using Autonomous JSON Database), how would I retrieve the desired document and send it back to the user in a JSON response?

I do notice that it's not possible to pass a JSON, JSON_OBJECT_T, or SODA_DOCUMENT_T directly, nor converting them into CLOB/BLOB and then pass, into a RESULTSET variable for output.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SODA for PL/SQL package, you can construct a QBE filter string. This will get allow you to work with the SODA_DOCUMENT_T types. Once you've got the document you would like (or a collection to loop through), you can then serialise it to text and output that in your HTTP response.

Examples below assume you have a JSON database. You can more easily retrieve JSON column data using standard SQL.

```
DECLARE
    collection SODA_COLLECTION_T;
    doc        SODA_DOCUMENT_T;
    qbe        VARCHAR2(64);
BEGIN
    qbe := '{"id": {"$eq": ' || :id || '}}';
    
    collection := DBMS_SODA.OPEN_COLLECTION('MYCOLLECTION');
    doc := collection.find().filter(qbe).get_one();

    OWA_UTIL.mime_header('application/json');
    htp.P(JSON_SERIALIZE(doc.get_json));
END;
```

Alternatively, avoid using the SODA package altogether by using a standard cursor / RESULTSET output, although for each result in the RESULTSET output, there will be a 'json_document' key, and the actual document nested inside.

```
 DECLARE
     cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
 BEGIN
     OPEN cur for 
         select JSON_DOCUMENT 
         from "MYUSER"."MYCOLLECTION" 
         where JSON_EXISTS ( "JSON_DOCUMENT", '$?(@.id == $B0)' PASSING :id AS B0);
     :result := cur;
 END;
```